# Returning rowcount from CLR stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, clrstoredprocedure

If I have a stored procedure like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_update_dummy]
AS
BEGIN
  update update_dummy set value = value + 1 where id = 1
END
```

and call this using `executeUpdate` (from standard java.sql library) then the updated row count is returned to the Java program (assuming, of course, that the update statement updates a row in the table).

However if I execute a CLR stored procedure coded like this:

```
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
public static void clr_update_dummy()
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("context connection=true"))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("update update_dummy set value = value + 1 where id = 1", conn);

        conn.Open();

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Then the Java program does not get the updated row count (it seems to get a value of -1 returned). This is also what happens if I put `SET NOCOUNT ON` into the SQL stored procedure.

So it looks to me that a CLR stored procedure acts as if `SET NOCOUNT ON` is used.

Is there any way to code a CLR stored procedure so that row count can be picked up in the same way it is for a SQL stored procedure? Unfortunately it isn't possible to change the Java program (it is a 3rd party component) to, for example, pick up an OUTPUT parameter. I've looked at SqlContext.Pipe but there is nothing obvious there. Also I'm not sure of the mechanism by which the row count is returned to the executeUpdate procedure.

I can probably create a hack to get around the problem (Java executes a SQL stored procedure which in turn executes a CLR stored procedure for instance) but if possible I'd like to not introduce another layer into the call stack.

Comment: Side note: You shouldn't use the `sp_` prefix for stored procedure names - it's reserved for Microsoft's system procedures.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - I'm aware of that, I chose the name unwisely.

Comment: Do you need to use CLR? Is this simply to avoid using SQL?

Comment: @gbn - unfortunately it has to be a CLR. I would rather use SQL but we are building a complex facade to sit between an existing system and a number of databases. The CLR will have to break up an incoming request and then invoke stored procedures on the databases. We decided it was too complex for SQL after putting together a proof of concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably (if it makes sense to just be turning around and running a piece of SQL from inside your CLR procedure) want to call [`ExecuteAndSend`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.server.sqlpipe.executeandsend.aspx)

> In addition to any actual results, other messages and errors are also sent directly to the client.

```cs
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("update update_dummy set value = value + 1 where id = 1", conn);
conn.Open();

SqlContext.Pipe.ExecuteAndSend(command);
```

Comment: thanks, that works OK but only if I use SqlCommand. For some of the databases I have to use OdbcCommand which SqlContext.Pipe doesn't accept. Is there a way I can see what ExecuteAndSend is putting into the pipe? Perhaps if I call ExecuteReader and then go through the result set I'll get some idea...

Comment: Replacing ExecuteNonQuery with ExecuteReader and looking at the returned SqlDataReader I can see a RecordsAffected integer that tells me how many rows the update affected. However I'm not sure how to get this information back to the caller without using the Pipe.ExecuteAndSend method.

Comment: @KeithMiller - I've taken a quick look at the `SqlPipe` class and there don't seem to be any likely methods there. All I can think of is an ugly bodge - with the row count information in hand, construct an SQL query that will affect the same number of rows and execute that.

Comment: I think that may be the way to go. It's horrible but if it gets the job done it will be worth it. I'll post my results here.

Comment: I've taken @Damien_The_Unbeliever's advice and now have s SQL stored procedure that executes my CLR code and then does an update of a dummy table.